# SIRS Model Analysis

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, biology

Consider the SIRS model given by
\begin{align}
\frac{dS}{dt}&=-aSI+cR, \\
\frac{dI}{dt}&=aSI-bI, \\
\frac{dR}{dt}&=bI-cR. \\
\end{align}
Here $a,b,$ and $c$ are constants and $N=S+I+R$ such that $N'(t)=0$. Using the substitution $R=N-S-I$, the system of equations reduces to
\begin{align}
\frac{dS}{dt}&=-aSI+c\left(N-S-I\right), \\
\frac{dI}{dt}&=aSI-bI. \\
\end{align}
My question is, what happened to the equation for $R'(t)$? How has the system of three equations reduced to a system of two equations?

Comment: $R+S+I = N$, so $R' + S'+I' = N' = 0$ (' indicates derivative w.r.t. $t$), so knowing $S',I'$ gives $R'$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{cases}
\frac{dS}{dt}=-aSI+cR \\
\frac{dI}{dt}=aSI-bI \\
\frac{dR}{dt}=bI-cR \\
\end{cases}
\quad\implies\quad \frac{dS}{dt}+\frac{dI}{dt}+\frac{dR}{dt}=0$$
$$\frac{d(S+I+R)}{dt}=0\quad\implies\quad S+I+R=C_1$$
$C_1=$constant. $\quad R=C_1-S-I$ . Puting it into the original system of three equations leads to :

$$\frac{dS}{dt}=-aSI+c(C_1-S-I) \tag A$$
$$\frac{dI}{dt}=aSI-bI \tag B$$
$$-\frac{dS}{dt}-\frac{dI}{dt}=bI-c(C_1-S-I) \tag C$$

We observe that equation $(C)$ is equivalent to the sum of the equations $(A)$ and $(B)$. Thus equation $(C)$ can be forgotten. Only two equations are remaining. The system is reduced to two equations :
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{dS}{dt}=-aSI+c(C_1-S-I) \\
\frac{dI}{dt}=aSI-bI
\end{cases} \tag 2$$
Your question is, what happened to the equation for R′(t)?

Answer : This third equation didn't vanished as if by magic. The third equation is still here because it is the above equation $\frac{d(S+I+R)}{dt}=0$ which already led to :
$$R=C_1-S-I$$
This third equation will be used after solving the above system $(2)$ for $S(t)$ and $I(t)$ in order to find $R(t)$.